# Magic numbers of the Linux reboot() system call

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

[*The Linux Programming Interface*](http://man7.org/tlpi/) has an exercise in Chapter 3 that goes like this:

> When using the Linux-specific reboot()
>   system call to reboot the system, the
>   second argument, magic2, must be
>   specified as one of a set of magic
>   numbers (e.g., LINUX_REBOOT_MAGIC2).
>   What is the significance of these
>   numbers? (Converting them to
>   hexadecimal provides a clue.)

The man page tells us `magic2` can be one of LINUX_REBOOT_MAGIC2 (672274793), LINUX_REBOOT_MAGIC2A (85072278), LINUX_REBOOT_MAGIC2B (369367448), or LINUX_REBOOT_MAGIC2C (537993216). I failed to decipher their meaning in hex. I also looked at `/usr/include/linux/reboot.h`, which didn't give any helpful comment either.

I then searched in the kernel's source code for `sys_reboot`'s definition. All I found was a declaration in a header file.

Therefore, my first question is, what is the significance of these numbers? My second question is, where's `sys_reboot`'s definition, and how did you find it?

**EDIT**: I found the definition in `kernel/sys.c`. I only grepped for `sys_reboot`, and forgot to grep for the MAGIC numbers. I figured the definition must be hidden behind some macro trick, so I looked at the `System.map` file under `/boot`, and found it next to `ctrl_alt_del`. I then grepped for that symbol, which led me to the correct file. If I had compiled the kernel from source code, I could try to find which object file defined the symbol, and go from there.

Comment: I do not understand how to use the man pages to see the information about `magic2`. I run `man reboot` but there is no mention of magic2. What should I run?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Just a guess, but those numbers look more interesting in hex:

```
672274793 = 0x28121969
 85072278 = 0x05121996
369367448 = 0x16041998
537993216 = 0x20112000
```

Developers' or developers' children's birthdays?

Regarding finding the syscall implementation, I did a `git grep -n LINUX_REBOOT_MAGIC2` and found the definition in kernel/sys.c. The symbol `sys_reboot` is generated by the `SYSCALL_DEFINE4(reboot, ...` gubbins, I suspect.

Comment: Dec 28, 1969 is Linus Torvalds' birth date [Wikipedia].  The others appear to be his children's birth dates, though I can only confirm one was born in December 1996 [random googling].

Comment: Confirmed, they are the birth dates of Linus and his 3 daughters. -> http://www.nndb.com/people/444/000022378/

Comment: but my question is: why magic is required for this system call? My guess is to avoid rebooting after an accidental and unintended call to it. ie: the first thing the system call does before proceeding is to verify that the required magic is present...

Comment: I would guess the intent for requiring 64 bit worth of semi-random magic values is intended to avoid accidental reboot in case any process accidentally calls system calls with uninitialized (or otherwise corrupted) memory.

Answer (score 31):

It's the birthday of Linus Torvalds (The developer of the Linux kernel and the Git version control) and his 3 daughters. works as magic numbers to reboot the system.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linus_Torvalds