# system call reboot and magic numbers

Tags: c, ubuntu-10.04, system-calls

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Magic numbers of the Linux reboot() system call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808748/magic-numbers-of-the-linux-reboot-system-call)

I was asked this question in an interview

> When using the Linux-specific reboot()
>   system call to reboot the system, the
>   second argument, magic2, must be
>   specified as one of a set of magic
>   numbers (e.g., LINUX_REBOOT_MAGIC2).
>   What is the significance of these
>   numbers?

What is the correct answer to the above question?

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808748

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The significance of the allowed set of magic2 numbers is that, when expressed in hexadecimal, they represent dates-of-birth (specifically, of Linus Torvalds and his three children).

This *really* lowers the bar on silly interview questions!

Comment: I really wonder if the interviewer wasn't trying to get at the point that the syscall uses magic numbers (their value doesn't matter so much) so that when testing asm that makes syscalls as root you don't accidentally reboot the machine. :-)